# Deposit in FunctionCallAction and TransferAction

Tags: nearprotocol

Consider FunctionCallAction and a TransferAction

```rust
pub struct FunctionCallAction {
    // ...
    pub deposit: Balance,
}


pub struct TransferAction {
    pub deposit: Balance,
}
```

What is the difference between `deposit` in `FunctionCallAction` and `TransferAction`?

Answer (score 2):

On a surface, it looks like `FunctionCallAction` duplicates the functionality of `TransferAction` by re-implementing the deposit. For instance, one could argue that we could get rid of `deposit` in `FunctionCallAction` and when we need to send some balance together with function call we could have two actions in the transaction: one for transfer and another for function call. However, we currently do not expose information to the smart contract on how many tokens were collectively deposited by all previous actions in the transactions, which is useful information for payable smart contract APIs. So currently when someone wants to write a smart contract that has certain associated cost expressed in tokens they can assert that these tokens were deposited with `FunctionCallAction::deposit` through `env::attached_balance` https://github.com/nearprotocol/near-bindgen/blob/master/near-bindgen/src/environment/env.rs#L149 .

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that it's an only difference that in the `deposit` in the FunctionCallAction is exposed as `env::attached_balance` in the contract environment?

Comment: Sort of. There is no way to access "attached balance" if it was "attached" through token transfers in other actions in the same receipt